# Insert Graphic in Title Section of Beamer Poster

Tags: beamer, titles, beamerposter, posters

How can I insert a graphic on the right edge of the title section, without de-centering the title text? My code is below (apologies for posting the entire code; I couldn't figure out a MWE):

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Jacobs Landscape Poster
% LaTeX Template
% Version 1.0 (29/03/13)
%
% Created by:
% Computational Physics and Biophysics Group, Jacobs University
% https://teamwork.jacobs-university.de:8443/confluence/display/CoPandBiG/LaTeX+Poster
% 
% Further modified by:
% Nathaniel Johnston (nathaniel@njohnston.ca)
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% License:
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[final]{beamer}

\usepackage[scale=1.24]{beamerposter} % Use the beamerposter package for laying out the poster

\usetheme{confposter} % Use the confposter theme supplied with this template

\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=ngreen,bg=white} % Colors of the block titles
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,bg=white} % Colors of the body of blocks
\setbeamercolor{block alerted title}{fg=white,bg=dblue!70} % Colors of the highlighted block titles
\setbeamercolor{block alerted body}{fg=black,bg=dblue!10} % Colors of the body of highlighted blocks
% Many more colors are available for use in beamerthemeconfposter.sty

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{labelformat=empty,labelsep=none}

%-----------------------------------------------------------
% Define the column widths and overall poster size
% To set effective sepwid, onecolwid and twocolwid values, first choose how many columns you want and how much separation you want between columns
% In this template, the separation width chosen is 0.024 of the paper width and a 4-column layout
% onecolwid should therefore be (1-(# of columns+1)*sepwid)/# of columns e.g. (1-(4+1)*0.024)/4 = 0.22
% Set twocolwid to be (2*onecolwid)+sepwid = 0.464
% Set threecolwid to be (3*onecolwid)+2*sepwid = 0.708

\newlength{\sepwid}
\newlength{\onecolwid}
\newlength{\twocolwid}
\newlength{\threecolwid}
\setlength{\paperwidth}{48in} % A0 width: 46.8in
\setlength{\paperheight}{36in} % A0 height: 33.1in
\setlength{\sepwid}{0.024\paperwidth} % Separation width (white space) between columns
\setlength{\onecolwid}{0.22\paperwidth} % Width of one column
\setlength{\twocolwid}{0.464\paperwidth} % Width of two columns
\setlength{\threecolwid}{0.708\paperwidth} % Width of three columns
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.5in} % Reduce the top margin size
%-----------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{graphicx}  % Required for including images

\usepackage{booktabs} % Top and bottom rules for tables

\usepackage{array,tabularx}

\usepackage{multirow} %results table

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE SECTION 
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\title{Detecting Multi-word Expressions Through Typing Patterns} % Poster title

\author{Adam G} % Author(s)

\institute{Department of Linguistics} % Institution(s)

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\addtobeamertemplate{block end}{}{\vspace*{2ex}} % White space under blocks
\addtobeamertemplate{block alerted end}{}{\vspace*{2ex}} % White space under highlighted (alert) blocks
\setbeamertemplate{caption}{\insertcaption} \setbeamertemplate{caption label separator}{} %no captions figure #

\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{2ex} % White space under figures
\setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{2ex} % White space under equations

\begin{frame}[t] % The whole poster is enclosed in one beamer frame

\begin{columns}[t] % The whole poster consists of three major columns, the second of which is split into two columns twice - the [t] option aligns each column's content to the top

\begin{column}{\sepwid}\end{column} % Empty spacer column

\begin{column}{\onecolwid} % The first column


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   THE PROBLEM
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\setbeamercolor{block alerted body}{fg=black,bg=white} % Change the alert block body colors
\begin{block}{The Problem}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{GooglePic.jpg}
\caption{Do they need a chiropractor or a stress ball?}
\end{figure}
\end{block}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   MULTI-WORD EXPRESSIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\setbeamercolor{block alerted body}{fg=black,bg=white} % Change the alert block body colors
\begin{block}{Multi-Word Expressions}

The phrase \textit{pain in the neck} can have two different meanings, either the literal meaning, or
the figurative meaning.
\end{block}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   MWE DEFINITION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 \setbeamercolor{block alerted body}{fg=black,bg=dblue!10} % Change the alert block body colors
\begin{alertblock}{What is a multi-word expression?}

A \textit{multi-word expression} (MWE) is a word collocation that exhibits markedly peculiar
linguistic behavior in terms of lexicalization, syntax or semantics. (Kunchukuttan 2007) \\
~\\
In other words: \\
$\mathrm{def}(word_{1}) \;+ \;\mathrm{def}(word_{2}) \neq \mathrm{def}(word_{1}+word_{2})$


\end{alertblock}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   MWEs IN SPEECH
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{block}{MWEs in Speech}
MWEs are theorized to be stored and retrieved as a single lexical unit (Wray 2005). Often,
the pause length is longer surrounding an MWE, and shorter within an MWE. (Dahlmann \& Adolphs 2007)
\begin{figure}
She\underline{\hspace{2cm}}looked\underline{\hspace{.40cm}}up\underline{\hspace{2cm}}
    the\underline{\hspace{2cm}}world\underline{\hspace{.40cm}}record\underline{\hspace{2cm}}
\end{figure}

\end{block}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   QUESTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\setbeamercolor{block alerted title}{fg=white,bg=ngreen} % Change the alert block title colors 
\setbeamercolor{block alerted body}{fg=black,bg=dgreen!10} % Change the alert block body colors
\begin{alertblock}{?? Question ??}

\centering{Can we apply speech prosody to keyboard typed text, to distinguish MWEs from other text?}

\end{alertblock}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


\end{column} % End of the first column

\begin{column}{\sepwid}\end{column} % Empty spacer column

\begin{column}{\twocolwid} % Begin a column which is two columns wide (column 2)


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   KD TO THE RESCUE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\setbeamercolor{block alerted title}{fg=yellow,bg=nblue!90} % Change the alert block title colors 
\setbeamercolor{block alerted body}{fg=black,bg=red!50} % Change the alert block body colors
\begin{alertblock}{\textbf{Keystroke Dynamics to the Rescue!}}

\centering{\textbf{Keystroke dynamics (KD) measures the timing of every computer keystroke, from the time a key
is pressed to the time it is released.}}

\end{alertblock} 

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   MWEs IN TYPED TEXT
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{block}{Detecting MWEs in Typing}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{r l}
  \bf{Assumption 1}: & MWEs have unique prosodic characteristics \\
  \bf{Assumption 2}: & Keystroke Dynamics is the reflection of prosody in typing \\
  \bf{Conclusion}:   & MWEs should be uniquely characterized in typing \\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{block}

\begin{columns}[t,totalwidth=\twocolwid] % Split up the two columns wide column

\begin{column}{\onecolwid}\vspace{-.6in} % The first column within column 2 (column 2.1)

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   MATERIALS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{block}{Materials}

\begin{itemize}
\item 1,013 college students
\item Recorded subjects clickstream (keystrokes)
\item Recorded clickstream timing (key up/down)
\item Subjects respond to a randomized question set
\item Subjects can skip to next question after typing 300 characters

\end{itemize}

\end{block}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{column} % End of column 2.1

\begin{column}{\onecolwid}\vspace{-.6in} % The second column within column 2 (column 2.2)

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   METHODOLGY
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{block}{Methodoology}

From the keystroke timing data, we determined the length of pause before each word. Each word was then categorized into one of four positions, relative to an MWE: outside, starting, middle of, and ending an MWE.


\end{block}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{column} % End of column 2.2

\end{columns} % End of the split of column 2 - any content after this will now take up 2 columns width

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   DEMOGRAPHICS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\centering{\bf{Subject Demographics}}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{demog.jpg}
\end{figure}
\centering{Typing Rate}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[]{typingrate.png}
\end{figure}



%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{column} % End of the second column

\begin{column}{\sepwid}\end{column} % Empty spacer column

\begin{column}{\onecolwid} % The third column

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   RESULTS!
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\setbeamercolor{block alerted title}{fg=white,bg=nred} % Change the alert block title colors
\setbeamercolor{block alerted body}{fg=black,bg=white} % Change the alert block body colors
\begin{alertblock}{!! Results !!}
\centering{\textbf{\textsc{Mean Pauses Before Word Location}}}
%\fontsize{30}{32}\selectfont{
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{@{}llllll@{}}
\toprule
                                      &               & \textbf{Start} & \textbf{Middle} & \textbf{End}   & \textbf{Outside} \\ \midrule
\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{\hspace{0.5cm}L1}}     & \textbf{Fast} & 429            & 220             & 31152          & 8839             \\ \cmidrule(l){2-6} 
                                      & \textbf{Slow} & 3787           & 491             & 137456         & 33773            \\ \midrule
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{L1 Mean}}             & \textbf{1594}  & \textbf{370}    & \textbf{62810} & \textbf{19375}   \\ \midrule
\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{\hspace{0.3cm}L2}} & \textbf{Fast} & 799            & 250             & 74984          & 11866            \\ \cmidrule(l){2-6} 
                                      & \textbf{Slow} & 2709           & 187             & 123149         & 43385            \\ \midrule
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{L2 Mean}}         & \textbf{1718}  & \textbf{519}    & \textbf{87086} & \textbf{27547}   \\ \midrule
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Overall}}             & \textbf{1616}  & \textbf{397}    & \textbf{67252} & \textbf{20888}   \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
%}
All figures are normalized for predictability \\ (Ask me what that is!)

\begin{itemize}
    \item Typists pause for significantly shorter lengths of time in the middle of MWEs
    \item While slow typists were 4x slower than fast typists outside of an MWE, the two groups were much closer within MWEs
    \item Slow L1 English speakers are slower than slow L2 English speakers
\end{itemize}


\end{alertblock}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   FUTURE STEPS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{block}{Future Steps}

\begin{itemize}
\item Build an MWE Detector, bottom-up
\item Does this improve information Retrieval?
\item Can we extend this to other languages?
\end{itemize}

\end{block}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CONTACT INFORMATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\setbeamercolor{block alerted title}{fg=black,bg=norange} % Change the alert block title colors
\setbeamercolor{block alerted body}{fg=black,bg=white} % Change the alert block body colors

\begin{alertblock}{Contact Information}

\begin{itemize}
\item Web: \href{http://www.adamg.com}{htttp://www.adamg.com}
\item Email: \href{mailto:a.g@gmail.com}{a.g@gmail.com}
\end{itemize}

\end{alertblock}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=red,bg=white} % Change the block title color

\begin{block}{Acknowledgements}

\small{\rmfamily{Thank you to my advisor, 

\end{block}



\end{column} % End of the third column

\end{columns} % End of all the columns in the poster

\end{frame} % End of the enclosing frame

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you post a link to the conftheme file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Title format is defined in `headline` template in `beamerthemeconfposter.sty` file.
The original one is defined as

```
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{
 \leavevmode
  \begin{columns}
   \begin{column}{\linewidth}
    \vskip1cm
    \centering
    \usebeamercolor{title in headline}{\color{jblue}\Huge{\textbf{\inserttitle}}\\[0.5ex]}
    \usebeamercolor{author in headline}{\color{fg}\Large{\insertauthor}\\[1ex]}
    \usebeamercolor{institute in headline}{\color{fg}\large{\insertinstitute}\\[1ex]}
    \vskip1cm
   \end{column}
   \vspace{1cm}
  \end{columns}
 \vspace{0.5in}
 \hspace{0.5in}\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=47in,colsep=0.15cm]{cboxb}\end{beamercolorbox}
 \vspace{0.1in}
}
```

where you can see how the title is defined inside a `column` which occupies total poster width (`\linewidth`). If you want to include an image on right side while keeping a central and centered title, you can divide this space in three columns, one empty on the left side, the title on the second and the third one for the image.If first and third columns use the same size, the second one will be centred. This is what is done in next code

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage[scale=1.24]{beamerposter} % Use the beamerposter package for laying out the poster

\usetheme{confposter} % Use the confposter theme supplied with this template

%-----------------------------------------------------------
% Define the column widths and overall poster size
% To set effective sepwid, onecolwid and twocolwid values, first choose how many columns you want and how much separation you want between columns
% In this template, the separation width chosen is 0.024 of the paper width and a 4-column layout
% onecolwid should therefore be (1-(# of columns+1)*sepwid)/# of columns e.g. (1-(4+1)*0.024)/4 = 0.22
% Set twocolwid to be (2*onecolwid)+sepwid = 0.464
% Set threecolwid to be (3*onecolwid)+2*sepwid = 0.708

\newlength{\sepwid}
\newlength{\onecolwid}
\newlength{\twocolwid}
\newlength{\threecolwid}
\setlength{\paperwidth}{48in} % A0 width: 46.8in
\setlength{\paperheight}{36in} % A0 height: 33.1in
\setlength{\sepwid}{0.024\paperwidth} % Separation width (white space) between columns
\setlength{\onecolwid}{0.22\paperwidth} % Width of one column
\setlength{\twocolwid}{0.464\paperwidth} % Width of two columns
\setlength{\threecolwid}{0.708\paperwidth} % Width of three columns
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.5in} % Reduce the top margin size
%-----------------------------------------------------------

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE SECTION 
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\title{Detecting Multi-word Expressions Through Typing Patterns} % Poster title

\author{Adam G} % Author(s)

\institute{Department of Linguistics} % Institution(s)

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{
 \leavevmode
  \begin{columns}
   \begin{column}{.1\linewidth}
   \end{column}
   \begin{column}{.8\linewidth}
    \vskip1cm
    \centering
    \usebeamercolor{title in headline}{\color{jblue}\Huge{\textbf{\inserttitle}}\\[0.5ex]}
    \usebeamercolor{author in headline}{\color{fg}\Large{\insertauthor}\\[1ex]}
    \usebeamercolor{institute in headline}{\color{fg}\large{\insertinstitute}\\[1ex]}
    \vskip1cm
   \end{column}
   \begin{column}{.1\linewidth}
    \includegraphics{image-A.jpg}
   \end{column}
   \vspace{1cm}
  \end{columns}
 \vspace{0.5in}
 \hspace{0.5in}\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=47in,colsep=0.15cm]{cboxb}\end{beamercolorbox}
 \vspace{0.1in}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t] % The whole poster is enclosed in one beamer frame

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]